# Splash screen (after login) looks bad

Tags: login, multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop and I connect to a HD monitor via HDMI. I don't need the laptop screen so I turn it off.

On the login screen, both the monitor and the laptop screens are turned on and showing correct image. When I type my password and press enter, the picture on my HD monitor will look like this:

[image]

The laptop screen shows correct image. After a few seconds, the laptop screen turns off, and the HD monitor will display:

[image]

After a few more seconds, the login is completed and my desktop appears correctly. How do I fix the splash screen?

I'm using the nvidia graphics driver, but I used to have exactly the same problem with the open-source driver.

Answer (score 0):

you will need your laptop screen, i'll tell you why:

first of all go to System-Setting>Displays.
then select the screen you're connected to

if you know your other screen resolution, set it and hit Apply. if you don't then start trying each one until the right one comes in.

if this does not work then your HDMI cable is 100% damaged and/or might have one of the wires inside damaged. this Problem is a Hardware problem and not a Software problem.

Comment: It is not a problem with my HDMI cable. I tried with a VGA cable, same problem. And if the cable was damaged, the desktop would not load correctly, would it?

Comment: Then, the problem is your VGA, maybe try upgrading your VGA card or use an external one!